# Dataset to Excel mulitple sheets using interop.excel in asp.net C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Dataset(mulitple data table) to Excel mulitple sheets using interop.excel in C#.net
Exporting dataset to Excel file with multiple sheets in ASP.NET
 this s the correct way to genereate excel

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        getquery();

    }

}
void getquery()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    string query = txt_query.Text;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_query_select", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition", query);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();         
        da.Fill(ds);
        query_grid.DataSource = ds;
        query_grid.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('please enter valid query');", true);
        query_grid.Visible = false;


    }
    finally
    {

        con.Close();
    }
}
private void Export_Excel()
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = txt_query_name.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    query_grid.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    query_grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    query_grid.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();      

}
public void ConvertToExcel(DataSet ds)
{
    getquery();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
    try
    {

        objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Add(ds.Tables.Count);
        int sheetcount = 1;

        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)objWB.Sheets.Add();

            objSHT.Name = "SheetData" + sheetcount.ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        objSHT.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                    }
                     objSHT.Cells[j + 2, i + 1] = dt.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                }
            }

            sheetcount++;
        }

        objWB.Saved = true;
        objWB.SaveCopyAs("C:\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx");

        objWB.Close();

        objXL.Quit();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        objWB.Saved = true;      
        objWB.Close();

        objXL.Quit();
        Response.Write("Illegal permission");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this s the correct way to genereate excel or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Generate Excel with Multiple Sheets from gridview using asp.net c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513059/how-to-generate-excel-with-multiple-sheets-from-gridview-using-asp-net-c-sharp)